# How to grab data from an html table cell and pass it to a variable in the components ts file in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to grab the value of a cell in an HTML table of only one row, and store it in a variable in my components ts file. It's important to mention that this table is usually empty and when a user clicks a button, the table is populated with data (1 row only) and I need to grab the value of a cell once there's data in the table:

Part of the html code related to the table:

```
<tr *ngFor="let d of empData" (change)="selectChangeEmpHandler($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedFirstName">
<td >{{d.id}}</td>
<td>{{d.firstName}}</td>
<td>{{d.lastName}}</td>
<td>{{d.age}}</td>
<td>{{d.dateOfBirth}}</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Part of the components ts file code inside my class:

selectedFirstName: string="";

selectChangeEmpHandler(event:any){this.selectedFirstName= event.target.value;}

Notice, I am trying to use a change event to grab the value, and store it in a variable, however I am sure I am doing it wrong. What should I do to properly grab that value?

Comment: Try event.target.innerHTML instead of event.target.value

Comment: I tried that, it did not work. Is there any way to bind the value of a table cell using any angular directive?

Comment: What I'd do is just give and ID to the cell you want to read from and use plain JS to getElementById and read the innerText.

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear, made a stackblitz earlier but forgot to paste it https://stackblitz.com/edit/html-basics-cxffz6?file=index.html